# How to implement an efficient Python algorithm for finding matching digits?

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, memory-efficient

Let's say I have 2 same-digit numbers A and B (both with distinct digits), I need to find X (number of digits in both A and B, and also in the same position), and Y (number of digits in both A and B, but are not in the same position).
For example, if A = 4567 and B = 4567, X would be 4, Y would be 0. If A = 3456 and B = 4567, X would be 0 and Y would be 3. Without considering the efficiency, my code is as follows:

```
def compare(num1, num2):
  x = 0
  y = 0
  for i in range(4):
     if str(num1)[i] in str(num2) and str(num1)[i] == str(num2)[i]:
        x += 1
     elif str(num1)[i] in str(num2):
        y += 1
  return ('X = %d, Y = %d'%(x,y))
```

However, I don't think this is the most efficient way of solving this problem. Could anyone offer a more efficient solution? Thanks...

Comment: Does your code work correctly (apart from the fact you didn’t format it properly here, I’m assuming it runs for you)? If so, is there a peraticular reason you’re worried about efficiency that motivates you to ask the question? Aren’t there other/different problems you could be spending your time solving?

Comment: It's an assignment problem which gives more marks for higher efficiency...

Comment: Looks like compare("0110", "1111") != compare("1111", "0110")

Comment: For this problem, the numbers have only distinct digits

Comment: Do you know how you’re going to measure the efficiency so you can decide what is better? And is efficiency just speed, or is it also other measures like lines of code, maintainability, memory needed,etc.?

Comment: In this case, the efficiency would be just the speed. I'm currently using timeit module to get the timings of different code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is only one way you can shorten it while keeping it neat.

```py
for i in range(4):
    if str(num1)[i] == str(num2)[i]:
        x += 1
    elif str(num1)[i] in str(num2):
        y += 1
```

The edit is in line 2, in the for loop. You wrote `if str(num1)[i] in str(num2) and str(num1)[i] == str(num2)[i]:`. There is no need for the `str(num1)[i] in str(num2)`, because if num1[i] is equal to num2[i], then it means that num1[i] is already in num2, so its a useless line of code.

If you just wanted to shorten down the lines, you could try this:

```py
for i in range(4):
        if str(num1)[i] == str(num2)[i]: x += 1
        elif str(num1)[i] in str(num2): y += 1
```

and

```py
x = y = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `dict` reduces number of comparisons.

`str(num1)[i] in str(num2):` scans the entire string again. You could avoid this.

```
def compare(num1, num2):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    result = {}

    num1 = str(num1)
    num2 = str(num2)

    for i in range(0,len(num1)):
        result[num1[i]] = i

    for i in range(0,len(num2)):
        if num2[i] in result:
            if result[num2[i]] == i:
                x +=1;
            else:
                y +=1;

    return ('X = %d, Y = %d'%(x,y))


print(compare(4567,4567))
print(compare(3456,4567))
```

Comment: This is much longer and less efficient than the OP answer. Also, what if num2 was longer than num1

Comment: For this problem, both numbers have the same number of digits

Comment: @ThePilotDude Why is it less efficient?

Comment: @JoverTay  Did you try this out? Any concerns you have with this approach?

Comment: So, the in query which you have written scans the entire the `num2` again. This means for 12345 and 98760, you ll have to do 25 comparisons instead of just 5 comparisons.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Firstly it takes longer, which means it is inefficient. Secondly, it uses 2 for loops, which would make it take longer anyway and make it harder to read. Thirdly, it is hard to read, which would make edit more difficult and, usually, make it take more time.

Comment: @ThePilotDude This does not take longer. If want, you can run it and check!. The OP has 2 nested loops. This has 2 normal loops. This is way faster. A huge misconception is that large lines in a code is bad! If the code is clean, it is better to do so! Hashing is way better than directly comparing any day! Simple `in` query is a O(n) compared to checking a hash key which is O(1). Just because, it is easy to implement, does'nt mean it is the right way!

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya I actually did time each one, and when I did, I saw that your one took 0.23 seconds longer. Also, where are the OP's two nested loops because I only see one.

Comment: @ThePilotDude `str(num1)[i] in str(num2):` is an internal loop. It checks if `str(num1)[i]` matches with any of `str(num2)` and hence an O(n) operation.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Alright well if `in` counts as a for loop, then that means that you use 3 loops so I don't see what your point is. More for loops almost always means less efficiency.

Comment: @ThePilotDude `in` for a `string` or `list` is O(n) but `in` for `dict` or `set` is O(1) and that's why this code block will be much faster. That is the basic optimization done here!

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya No because you are still iterating through every item in result to check if it contains`num2[i]`. I get your logic and everything, and it is shorter than using `in` in a string, but it still wastes time, making it less efficient. Generally, longer code is less efficient, because each line takes time up.

Comment: @ThePilotDude It does not iterate. It uses hashing. Long code means more time is a total misconception!

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya It's not a misconception, because each code takes time, so it will almost always take longer. This is a prime example of where it takes longer, because I timed it and it took longer.