# How do I reduce the time complexity of this code snippet in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, for-loop, time-complexity

I have a `compare` function here which compares 2 4-digit numbers (non-repeating digits) and gives `x` (no. of digits in both `n1` and `n2` and in the same position), and `y` (no. of digits in both `n1` and `n2`, but in different positions). What I do is I use a `for` loop to store the digit as the key of the `results` dictionary and the corresponding position as the value of the `results` dictionary. Then, I use another `for` loop to iterate through the dictionary to give me `x` and `y`. Is there any way of reducing the time complexity of this function?

```
def compare(n1, n2):
    x, y = 0, 0
    result = {}
    s1, s2 = str(n1), str(n2)
    for i in range(0, 4):
        result[s1[i]] = i 
    for i in range(0, 4):
        if s2[i] in result:
            if result[s2[i]] == i:
                x += 1
            else:
                y += 1
```

Comment: You cannot improve beyond O(n) for this task.

Comment: @DeGo so the current complexity of my code is O(n)? sorry, because I am not very familiar with the concept of time complexity...

Comment: Duplicates of your own questions:
@Jover Tay : you have been asking nearly the same question 3 times this month, please avoid duplicating question here on StackOverflow, you even don t even car to repeat the needed details and constraints like aolny 4 digits with non repeating digits  : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345736/how-to-implement-an-efficient-python-algorithm-for-finding-matching-digits
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67748271/how-do-i-reduce-the-time-complexity-of-this-code-snippet-in-python

Answer (score 0):

@DeGo said you can't go better than o(n). However, you code can be improved since you are doing things that are absolutely not necessary. I would rewrite the code as

```
from collections import Counter

def compare(n1, n2):
    digits_at_same_position, digits_at_diff_position = 0, 0
    s1, s2 = str(n1), str(n2)
    l1 = list(map(lambda x, y: x == y, s1, s2))
    digits_at_same_position = sum(l1)
    l2 = list((Counter(s1) & Counter(s2)).elements())
    digits_at_diff_position = len(l2) - digits_at_same_position
    return digits_at_same_position, digits_at_diff_position

print(compare(1234, 2435))
```

The class of efficiency is the same. However, this code will be faster than yours.

**Output:**

```
>> (1, 2)
```

Comment: this code does not work when the numbers are 1234 and 2435, because of the ```else```

Comment: @JoverTay I updated the code. This should work now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no possible way you can get x and y without accessing the whole list. Although you may sort the list with nlogn,

Comment: `O(n logn)` is worse than `O(n)`. I am not sure what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

`Numpy` give a better vectorized solution. So both loop is replace with a vectored solution as follows:

1. For `x` we directly compare each index value to other same index value and then use `np.sum` to count number which are same.
2. For `y` we just want value check in a array which can be done using `np.in1d` as a vectorized solution.

---

```
import numpy as np

def compare(n1, n2):
    s1, s2 = str(n1), str(n2)

    l1 = np.array(list(s1))
    l2 = np.array(list(s2))
    x = np.sum(l1 == l2)
    y = np.sum(np.in1d(l2, l1)) - x
    print(x, y)
    
compare(1023, 2024)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
2 1
```