# What is the time complexity of this Python code snippet?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I am trying to learn more about time complexity and I read that dictionary `in` has a O(1) complexity. So for the below function, is the time complexity O(n)?

```
def compare(n1, n2):
    x, y = 0, 0
    result = {}
    s1, s2 = str(n1), str(n2)
    for i in range(0, 4):
        result[s1[i]] = i
    for i in range(0, 4):
        if s2[i] in result:
            if result[s2[i]] == i:
                x += 1
            else:
                y += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please indicate what you think the time complexity should be in this case? (And what kind of understanding do you have regarding time complexity)

Comment: @GaneshTata I think the time complexity should be O(n). I don't really understand much yet, but from what I have seen on the internet, for loops generally have a complexity of O(n) and dictionary has a complexity of O(1) due to hash tables...

Comment: Please add this as part of the question @Jover.

Comment: _"for loops generally have a complexity of O(n)"_ That's wrong. Your for loops have a time complexity of O(1). They don't depend on a variable. They have a fixed number of iterations. The only dynamic part in your code is `str(n1), str(n2)`. This has a time complexity of O(n1 + n2). The larger the input numbers the longer this conversion will take. The rest of your code has a time complexity of O(1). So the whole code has a time complexity of O(n1 + n2).

Comment: @jabaa yeah, since the loop doesn't vary with the input, this algorithm will essentially be the complexity of converting `n1` and `n2` (`int`s, presumably?!) to strings. so still O(N), I think (or is it O(log n)?)

Comment: I think it's actually O(log10(n1) + log10(n2)) but I'm not sure how `str` is implemented.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What's `n`? Using an undefined variable in a big O notation is worthless.

Comment: @jabaa the magnitude of the integer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Which integer? There are multiple, at least 5. Two of them are inputs. None of them is called `n`.

Comment: @jabaa I mean the integers being converted to strings

Comment: In your case the time complexity is O(max(len(s1), len(s2))).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, ```n1``` and ```n2``` are ```int```s

Comment: @jabaa you are correct, nevermind

Comment: @Jover Tay : You may have bug if you numbers does not have exactly 4 digits in your code, you should improve this. And your forgot to return the results ...

Comment: @Jover Tay : you have been asking nearly the same question 3 times this month, please avoid duplicating question here on StackOverflow, you even don t even car to repeat the needed details and constraints like aolny 4 digits with non repeating digits  : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345736/how-to-implement-an-efficient-python-algorithm-for-finding-matching-digits
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67748271/how-do-i-reduce-the-time-complexity-of-this-code-snippet-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"for loops generally have a complexity of O(n)"*  That's wrong.

Your for loops have a time complexity of `O(1)`. They don't depend on a variable. They have a fixed number of iterations. The only dynamic part in your code is `str(n1), str(n2)`. This has a time complexity of `O(log10(n1) + log10(n2))`. The larger the input numbers the longer this conversion will take. The rest of your code has a time complexity of `O(1)`. So the whole code has a time complexity of `O(log10(n1) + log10(n2))`

```
def compare(n1, n2):
    x, y = 0, 0 # O(1)
    result = {} # O(1)
    s1, s2 = str(n1), str(n2) # O(log10(n1) + log10(n2))
    for i in range(0, 4): # O(4) == O(1)
        result[s1[i]] = i # O(1)
    for i in range(0, 4): # O(1)
        if s2[i] in result: # O(1)
            if result[s2[i]] == i: # O(1)
                x += 1 # O(1)
            else:
                y += 1 # O(1)
```

Comment: Oh you have to count the s1, s2 = str(n1), str(n2) operations ? it is a bit tricky to know the exact complexity of this part ?

Comment: @Malo The whole concept of analyzing time complexity is to find out how an algorithm or code behaves for large input. Ignoring parts of the code or algorithm yields wrong results. For `str` it's not so tricky to find upper and lower boundaries. It's obvious that `str` can't convert arbitrary long numbers to a string in `O(1)`. I know an algorithm to convert a number in `O(log10(n1))`.

Comment: OK thanks for details @jabaa but do we now the implementation details of this part ? and it is buggy as only the 4 digits case is handled properly in the code.

Comment: @Malo The question is about the time complexity of a specific code. I analyzed this specific code. If the code is buggy and has to be fixed the new code will probably have a different time complexity. It's possible that only the first 4 digits of a number are interesting and that the input always has at least 4 digits. In that case the code is correct. You don't know the use case for this code.

Comment: @Malo You can probably find out the exact time complexity of `str`. But `O(log10(n1)) == O(len(s1))` and I'm pretty sure `str` can't perform better because it has to write each character into memory.

Comment: your answer is fine, that s just my two cents, to warn the OP to work his code, which may have a different time complexity if implemented properly without bugs.

Comment: @jabaa thanks, I would like to clarify for the ```if s2[i] in result```, if ```result``` was a list, would the complexity still be O(1) or would it be O(n)?

Comment: @Malo thanks, but for this code, it only needs to serve 4-digit inputs.

Comment: @JoverTay If the input has always 4 digits the time complexity is `O(1)` because `O(log10(n1)) == O(4) == O(1)` for a 4 digit number. Accessing an arbitrary element in a linked list has a time complexity of `O(n)`. If it's implemented as contiguous memory it's `O(1)`. If it's a hash map it's `O(1)`. If it's a map based on a binary tree it's `O(log(n))`.

Comment: @JoverTay [Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) is a table with important complexities.

Answer (score -3):

Let's see: you have 2 loops, both performing dictionary operations and simple arithmetic. We can ignore them since arithmetic and dictionaries work in O(1). But, since you have 2 for loops, you're going over twice of your elements, therefore I would say, that your time complexity is O(2n). Time completely is just a fancy word, describing how many steps your algorithm will take with n elements.

Comment: "Time completely is just a fancy word, describing how many steps your algorithm will take with n elements." No, it isn't. This misses the crucial aspect of big-oh notation, i.e. O(2*N). **is O(N)**